# Getting Multiple items from Chrome storage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have 4 items which I'd like to get but I'm unsure how to separate the keys. Using comma gives an error. Here is an example of my usage:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    'customImage',
    'customColor',
    'customRandColor',
    'customRandImage'
  }, function(backgroundCheckedOptions) {
    document.getElementById('optionsCustomImage').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customImage;
    document.getElementById('optionsBackgroundColor').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customColor;
    document.getElementById('optionsRandomColor').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customRandColor;
    document.getElementById('optionsRandomImage').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customRandImage;
  });
```

I would have assumed they would be separated by a comma, but I guess not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [Chrome Storage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), it says:

> StorageArea.get(string or array of string or object keys, function callback)

Easiest would be to pass an array by replacing your `{}` with `[]`

Comment: Object form is also useful for giving default value: `{key1: default1, key2: default2}`

Answer (score 1):

As per the official [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) it will be as below.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get([
 'customImage',
 'customColor',
 'customRandColor',
 'customRandImage'
], function(backgroundCheckedOptions) {
 document.getElementById('optionsCustomImage').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customImage;
 document.getElementById('optionsBackgroundColor').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customColor;
 document.getElementById('optionsRandomColor').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customRandColor;
 document.getElementById('optionsRandomImage').checked = backgroundCheckedOptions.customRandImage;
});
```